# SharePoint 2013 - Deleted subsites not going in Recycle Bin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site, delete, recycle-bin

I am a bit confused with regards to the Recycle Bin when it comes to SharePoint 2013.

A few quick Google searches suggested that when one deletes a sub-site, the site will not be permanently deleted but it will go to the Site Recycle bin and then to the Site Collection Administration Recycle Bin.

However, whenever I try to create a sub-site and delete it, both the recycle bins are empty and the sub sites cannot be restored.

These are the steps I followed:

Create a Sub-Site

[image]
[image]

Delete a sub-site

[image]
[image]

Site Recycle Bin Contents

[image]

Site Content Administration Recycle Bin

[image]
Links:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-a-deleted-object-from-a-SharePoint-Recycle-Bin-dd5c00c2-aef6-4458-9d04-80b185077653#__toc294595530
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261680%28v=office.12%29.aspx
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-restore-or-delete-items-in-the-Recycle-Bin-of-a-SharePoint-site-6df466b6-55f2-4898-8d6e-c0dff851a0be
- https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/11/06/sharepoint-2013-recycle-bin.aspx

So do sub-sites get deleted permanently?

I read somewhere that you need about 50%(?) of storage quota for the items to be store in the recycle bin, however storage is not an issue as we did not surpass 50% of the allocated amount.

Comment: Deleted sub-sites should end up in the recycle bin. Just done a quick test and the deleted sub-site ended up in the site collection recycle bin (i.e. within the 'deleted from end user' recycle bin).

Comment: couple of things to make sure, are you checking right site collection's recycle bin?  what is quota of site collection and how much free space? have you tried the same steps in different site collection, try to create brand new site collection and test it. reason for all this, this is not expected behaviour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Deleted subsites not going in Recycle Bin

They **are** there, but You should find them with this path:

http://server/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?**View=2**

...or **view=13** for he case of SharePoint Online

Comment: Is there a reason why the End User Recycle Bin was skipped and the site went directly to the Admi nRecycle Bin?

Comment: And what is the need to append ?View=2 to the end of the URL. Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I didn't architect it.. :)

Comment: View=2 switches to view that contains deleted webs(it is not default view)

Comment: So dumb... why doesn't SharePoint give you a way to get to this through the UI?